# Python: sum all the values with same key in json?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a Json file from i read. i would to print the sum of 'total_signatures'.

```
   {
        "response": [
            {
                
                "domains": [],
                "total_network_connections": 0,
                "total_processes": 0,
                "total_signatures": 0,
               
            },
            {
                "analysis_start_time": "2018-03-05 08:54:07",
                "avdetect": 52,
                "certificates": [],
                "classification_tags": [],
                "domains": [],
                "total_signatures": 55,
                "type": "PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows",
                "type_short": [
                    "peexe",
                    "executable"
                ],
                "verdict": "malicious",
                "vxfamily": "Trojan.Agent"
            },
            {
                "analysis_start_time": "2016-05-18 09:10:50",
                "avdetect": 52,
                "certificates": [],
                "classification_tags": [],
                "total_signatures": 35,

..............
```

I tried with this but doesn't work ---> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

```
  a = sum(d['total_signatures'] for d in data['response'].values() if d)
```

How can I solve This? Thank you

Comment: The answer to your question depends on the structure of the json. Please post complete details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
json = {...}
sum = 0
for i in json['response']:
    sum += (i['total_signatures'])
print(sum)
```

out:

```
90
```

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score -1):

This should do:

```
In [48]: d
Out[48]:
{'response': [{'domains': [],
   'total_network_connections': 0,
   'total_processes': 0,
   'total_signatures': 0},
  {'analysis_start_time': '2018-03-05 08:54:07',
   'avdetect': 52,
   'certificates': [],
   'classification_tags': [],
   'domains': [],
   'total_signatures': 55,
   'type': 'PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows',
   'type_short': ['peexe', 'executable'],
   'verdict': 'malicious',
   'vxfamily': 'Trojan.Agent'},
  {'analysis_start_time': '2016-05-18 09:10:50',
   'avdetect': 52,
   'certificates': [],
   'classification_tags': [],
   'total_signatures': 35}]}

In [49]: sum([x['total_signatures'] for x in d['response']])
Out[49]: 90
```

Comment: Nope :( ..i have this error--> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Perhaps you have a variable name called 'sum'. Try following: del sum and then run it again.  The only function called in this oneliner is sum. and the error you are suggesting says that you are calling an int type varible as a function so that appears to be sum.

Comment: it's very very big. can i send you on email? No, i haven't sum variable :(